# H2 not saving value and not throwing any exceptions

Tags: java, database, spring, h2

I am starting to work with h2 database.

I am using following code to persist a value in database -

```
public class MyDao extends NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {
  public void save() {
    System.out.println("Saving..");
    getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(
        "insert into mytable values(:time)",
        new MapSqlParameterSource("time", new Date()));
    System.out.println("Saved..");
  }
}
```

Spring config -

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool"
        destroy-method="dispose">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource">
            <property name="URL" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:8082/test/" />
            <property name="user" value="sa" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The code prints `Saving..` and then never prints `Saved..`. It freezes at the update statement.

No exception is being thrown. Why is this?

Edit:

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.4-b01 mixed mode, sharing):

"Thread-5" prio=6 tid=0x03fd9c00 nid=0x1dcc runnable [0x0887f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23a9d4d0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.value.Transfer.readInt(Transfer.java:151)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:560)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:111)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:395)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:287)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:92)
        at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getJdbcConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:181)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getXAConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:315)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource.getPooledConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:341)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnectionNow(JdbcConnectionPool.java:226)
        at org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool.getConnection(JdbcConnectionPool.java:199)
        - locked <0x23c127d8> (a org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:834)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:260)
        at com.kshitiz.data.db.MyDao.save(MyDao.java:14)
        at com.kshitiz.data.db.DatabaseDaemon.run(DatabaseDaemon.java:17)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Thread-3" prio=6 tid=0x063e8000 nid=0x1be4 waiting on condition [0x075cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at com.kshitiz.ReadDaemon.run(ReadDaemon.java:25)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Prism Font Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x03e2b000 nid=0x1918 in Object.wait() [0x072ff000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28f10b98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28f10b98> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.t2k.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:71)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Thread-2" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03ee3400 nid=0x10d0 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JavaFX Application Thread" prio=6 tid=0x03ede800 nid=0x1080 runnable [0x04b2f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x03eb2c00 nid=0x48c in Object.wait() [0x0416f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28d107b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28d107b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.utils.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"QuantumRenderer-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03eb2400 nid=0xee4 waiting on condition [0x040df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x28d10848> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:98)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"JavaFX-Launcher" prio=6 tid=0x03e17c00 nid=0xb1c waiting on condition [0x03c8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x28d220b8> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:330)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x015f4000 nid=0x1ed4 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x015ee400 nid=0x1df8 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x015ed000 nid=0x950 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x015e3400 nid=0x1b38 runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x015d7400 nid=0xb54 in Object.wait() [0x03a7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28d10d58> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28d10d58> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x015d2800 nid=0x1294 in Object.wait() [0x038cf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28d104e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28d104e8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"main" prio=6 tid=0x016bc400 nid=0x1f40 waiting on condition [0x016af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x28d10de0> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:134)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:75)
        at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:209)
        at com.kshitiz.ui.Main.main(Main.java:73)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x015d1400 nid=0x1f44 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01615c00 nid=0x1114 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 309
```

Server side thread dump -

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.4-b01 mixed mode, sharing):

"H2 Console thread" prio=6 tid=0x05ea2000 nid=0x15d8 runnable [0x04baf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x239da8c0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.readHeaderLine(WebThread.java:212)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:114)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Console thread" prio=6 tid=0x05ea1400 nid=0x1f54 runnable [0x04eef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23c120b8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.readHeaderLine(WebThread.java:212)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:114)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Console thread" prio=6 tid=0x05ea0c00 nid=0xd7c runnable [0x04e1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x23c141c8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.readHeaderLine(WebThread.java:212)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:114)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Console thread" prio=6 tid=0x05ea0800 nid=0x15f0 runnable [0x04caf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28ffe380> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.readHeaderLine(WebThread.java:212)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:114)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Console thread" prio=6 tid=0x05ea0000 nid=0xe54 runnable [0x0468f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x29000498> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.readHeaderLine(WebThread.java:212)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:114)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Console thread" prio=6 tid=0x05e9fc00 nid=0x328 runnable [0x03d0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x29009958> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.readHeaderLine(WebThread.java:212)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:114)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Log Writer TEST" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0409e800 nid=0x31c in Object.wait() [0x04d8f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x29000688> (a org.h2.store.WriterThread)
        at org.h2.store.WriterThread.run(WriterThread.java:104)
        - locked <0x29000688> (a org.h2.store.WriterThread)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 File Lock Watchdog C:/Users/kshitiz/test.lock.db" daemon prio=10 tid=0x03ed6400 nid=0x1154 waiting on condition [0x0498f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at org.h2.store.FileLock.run(FileLock.java:492)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 TCP Server (tcp://192.168.1.145:9092) thread" prio=6 tid=0x03f08800 nid=0x1764 runnable [0x04bfe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x29004920> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.value.Transfer.readInt(Transfer.java:151)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:246)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:149)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Console thread" prio=6 tid=0x04008400 nid=0x17c0 runnable [0x04b1f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28f309c0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.readHeaderLine(WebThread.java:212)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.process(WebThread.java:114)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebThread.run(WebThread.java:93)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"DestroyJavaVM" prio=6 tid=0x017eb800 nid=0x1b38 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 PG Server (pg://192.168.1.145:5435)" prio=6 tid=0x03fd3000 nid=0xb3c runnable [0x0629f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28f30ba0> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.server.pg.PgServer.listen(PgServer.java:182)
        at org.h2.tools.Server.run(Server.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 TCP Server (tcp://192.168.1.145:9092)" prio=6 tid=0x03fda000 nid=0xa10 runnable [0x04f9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28e03a88> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServer.listen(TcpServer.java:239)
        at org.h2.tools.Server.run(Server.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"AWT-EventQueue-0" prio=6 tid=0x03f30c00 nid=0x18a4 waiting on condition [0x04a6f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x28e03c90> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"AWT-Windows" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03efa800 nid=0x1cd8 runnable [0x0471f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop(Native Method)
        at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"AWT-Shutdown" prio=6 tid=0x03f6a000 nid=0x1920 in Object.wait() [0x047af000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28e03df8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28e03df8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Java2D Disposer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x03f3c000 nid=0x18bc in Object.wait() [0x045df000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28e03e88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28e03e88> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"H2 Console Server (http://192.168.1.145:8082)" prio=6 tid=0x03edd800 nid=0x1298 runnable [0x03b0f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28e03f68> (a java.net.SocksSocketImpl)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.listen(WebServer.java:341)
        at org.h2.tools.Server.run(Server.java:544)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Service Thread" daemon prio=6 tid=0x0199f000 nid=0x15ac runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0198ec00 nid=0x18d0 waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0198d000 nid=0x103c waiting on condition [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0198a000 nid=0x1efc runnable [0x00000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x01973400 nid=0x1d0c in Object.wait() [0x03abf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28e04220> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28e04220> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x01971c00 nid=0x1e30 in Object.wait() [0x0185f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x28e03970> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0x28e03970> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x01970800 nid=0x15b0 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x019a9c00 nid=0x19e8 waiting on condition

JNI global references: 604
```

Comment: Could you get a full thread dump and post it? To get the process id, run `jps -l` on the command line, then run `jstack -l <pid>` to get the full thread dump.

Comment: @KshitizSharma what about the server side, could you post that full thread dump as well? Actually I would check first if the H2 server version is the same as the client (in theory it shouldn't be a problem but in the past there were some compatibilities).

Comment: @ThomasMueller Done that too. The client and server are both running 1.3.168

Comment: @ThomasMueller The problem goes away if I change the database url string to `localhost` instead of `localhost:8082`. I don't understand why this is happening though. Isn't it supposed to run on port 8082?

Comment: @KshitizSharma the default port for the web server is 8082, but that's the wrong server. You don't want to connect to the web server, you want to connect to the TCP server. And there the default port is 9092.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Perhaps you should make this an answer so I could select it. I could delete the question but better keep it here for anyone that may enter the same ditch in future.

Comment: @ThomasMueller And maybe H2 should contain a check to throw an appropriate exception in this case instead of just hanging up. Just sayin..

Comment: @KshitizSharma Well the TCP server doesn't respond yet, so the client has to wait. Of course there is a timeout. If you know how to solve the problem, patches are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the jdbc url which should contain `localhost:9092` and not `localhost:8082`.

To quote Thomas Mueller from his comment above -

> The default port for the web server is 8082, but that's the wrong
>   server. You don't want to connect to the web server, you want to
>   connect to the TCP server. And there the default port is 9092.